# How to create user and attach new claims in a firebase transaction

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I would like to create user and attach new claims.

However, I want to reverse user creation if claims attachment fails. I think I'd need to use a transaction, but there does not seem to be any for authentication client.

Is there a way to achieve the desired result ?

Currently I just rely on success confidence. I create a user. I then attach new claims to him.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to cancel the creation of a user once they've been created. All you can do at that point is disable or delete their account, but neither of those will invalidate their existing/initial token - which is valid for up to an hour.